# WPF ComboBox: static list of ComboBoxItems, but databound SelectedItem?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox

In my WPF application, I have a ComboBox that is filled with a static list of ComboBoxItems because its contents will never change. However, because I want to databind the SelectedItem to my underlying ViewModel, I want each ComboBoxItem to also have a separate value that is to be assigned to my ViewModel property. And I'm having a bit of trouble to get this working.

My ComboBox declaration looks like:

```
    <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top"
              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Amount, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedValuePath="Tag" >
        <ComboBoxItem Content="None" Tag="0" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Few" Tag="1" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Some" Tag="2" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Enough" Tag="3" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Lots" Tag="4" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Too much" Tag="5" />
    </ComboBox>
```

The SelectedItem of this ComboBox is bound to the ViewModel's Amount property, which is declared as an integer:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _amount = 3;

    public int Amount
    {
        get { return _amount; }
        set
        {
            _amount = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Amount");
        }
    }

    //...
}
```

I was hoping that SelectedValuePath="Tag" would tell WPF that it should use the Tag value to bind to the ViewModel's Amount property, but  when I run this application and change the ComboBox's selected item, the debug trace tells me:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 23 : Cannot convert 'System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: Some' from type 'ComboBoxItem' to type 'System.Int32' for 'en-US' culture ...
System.Windows.Data Error: 7 : ConvertBack cannot convert value 'System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: Some' (type 'ComboBoxItem'). (...) System.NotSupportedException: Int32Converter cannot convert from System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem.
```

Apparently, it tries to bind the entire ComboBoxItem to my ViewModel, not just its Tag value. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you use `SelectedValuePath` then you need to bind to the [SelectedValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvalue.aspx) property which is

> Gets or sets the value of the SelectedItem, obtained by using SelectedValuePath

So modify your binding to

```
SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Amount, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

because as you experienced the `SelectedItem` will always contain the actually selected item (in your case the `ComboBoxItem`) not the value.

Comment: Wow, that was easy... Also, I now 'get' where I went wrong. Thanks for your explanation!