# Getting a s:String out of a ComboBoxItem

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

Using MVVM and WPF, I have a `ComboBox` with 7 items created statically. As I choose one of them, it will then define the type of a certain attribute.

Until now, these items are only strings that I pass to the set of a property `ItemType`. I would like to **add an `Image` beside each string**, so the user can identify the different types more easily. I could do it following the thousands of examples I've seen through googling, but in my case, the way things are structured is making me go nuts and I can't make it work. Any ideas would be highly appreciated.

**View.xaml:**

```
<ComboBox MinWidth="50" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=ItemType,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <ComboBox.Items>
        <s:String>Type1</s:String>
        <s:String>Type2</s:String>
        <s:String>Type3</s:String>
        <s:String>Type4</s:String>
        <s:String>Type5</s:String>
        <s:String>Type6</s:String>
        <s:String>Type7</s:String>
    </ComboBox.Items>
</ComboBox>
```

**ViewModel.cs:**

```
string _ItemType;
public string ItemType
{
    get
    {
        return _ItemType;
    }
    set
    {
        _ItemType = value;
        switch (value)
        {
            case "Type1":
                //Do whatever;
                break;
            case "Type2":
                //Do whatever;
                break;
            case "Type3":
                //Do whatever;
                break;
            case "Type4":
                //Do whatever;
                break;
            case "Type5":
                //Do whatever;
                break;
            case "Type6":
                //Do whatever;
                break;
            case "Type7":
                //Do whatever;
                break;
            default:
                break;

        }
        RaisePropertyChanged("ItemType");
    }
}
```

Comment: Just use ComboBoxItem instead of s:String and there is will be no headache

Comment: Yep, my first thought, but then I get `System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem` in `value`. Not good.

Comment: Not good is to use such code :) Sorry if it sound too cruel. Same question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12550926/wpf-combobox-static-list-of-comboboxitems-but-databound-selecteditem If i will write answer on your question, it will be same

Comment: So you'd better, cause you are correct, my friend! Or should I just delete the question, as it seems to be a duplicate? Anyway, thank you sir.

Comment: He's right though. WPF was designed to be data driven, the "correct" method is to create a custom data structure, place an array of them in your view model and use that to drive the graphics. You've started on the wrong foot by declaring your data in XAML, which is fine if all you need is strings but creates problems as soon as you need to introduce even one more element. There are in fact ways to do exactly what you're trying to do, but it'll break again with a 3rd item...and then a 4th...and so on. Best to correct the architecture now while it's easy to do so.